# Value Error when trying to train a spacy model

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy, spacy-3

I tried training a spacy model but recently I started to get some errors , i got the below error and i would like some one to help me resolve error

```
def train_model(model, train_data, optimizer, batch_size, epochs=10):
        losses = {}
        random.seed(1)
    
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            random.shuffle(train_data)
    
            batches = minibatch(train_data, size=batch_size)
            for batch in batches:
                # Split batch into texts and labels
                texts, labels = zip(*batch)
    
                # Update model with texts and labels
                nlp.update(texts, labels, sgd=optimizer, losses=losses)
            print("Loss: {}".format(losses['textcat']))
    
        return losses['textcat']




optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
batch_size = 5
epochs = 20
    
# Training the model
train_model(nlp, train_data, optimizer, batch_size, epochs)
```

Below is the error which shows that there is a value error

```
ValueError                                                       
                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16120/3494358196.py in <module>
      4 
      5 # Training the model
----> 6 train_model(nlp, train_data, optimizer, batch_size, epochs)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16120/3158014372.py in train_model(model, train_data, optimizer, batch_size, epochs)
     12 
     13             # Update model with texts and labels
---> 14             nlp.update(texts, labels, sgd=optimizer, losses=losses)
     15         print("Loss: {}".format(losses['textcat']))
     16 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py in update(self, examples, _, drop, sgd, losses, component_cfg, exclude, annotates)
   1132         """
   1133         if _ is not None:
-> 1134             raise ValueError(Errors.E989)
   1135         if losses is None:
   1136             losses = {}

ValueError: [E989] `nlp.update()` was called with two positional arguments. This may be due to a backwards-incompatible change to the format of the training data in spaCy 3.0 onwards. The 'update' function should now be called with a batch of Example objects, instead of `(text, annotation)` tuples.
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you didn't show FULL error, we can't run this code, and we can't read in your mind - so we can't helpy. You have to add all details in question (not in comments)

Comment: I have rephrased the question with the error , hope it helps , thanks @TalhaTayyab

Comment: I have rephrased the question with the error , hope it helps , thanks @furas

Comment: did you read error message: `"This may be due to a backwards-incompatible change to the format of the training data in spaCy 3.0 onwards."`? Maybe you updated modules and now they need different code. You may try to install older version. OR you may check in documentation how to use new version.

Comment: I tried installing the older versions but its not happening , i'm going through the updated documentation for now ,please check the new documentation and let me know if you find anything @furas

Comment: in documentation on [this page](https://spacy.io/usage/v3) I found (using `Ctr+F` and word `update`) that it should be `nlp.update(batch)` but I don't know it can get also `sgd=optimizer, losses=losses`

Comment: Okay , what changes could we make in the above code , i'll give it a try @furas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on [documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/v3) they made some changes in version `3.x` and now it uses directly `batch` without spliting `texts, labels = zip(*batch)`.

```
            for batch in batches:
                nlp.update(batch, sgd=optimizer, losses=losses)
```

That's all.